# valign=“top” not working in td

Tags: html, css, html-table, valign

My problem is posted as "solved" here, but apparently I don't understand the solution (?). I have piles of legacy html that appears to be starting to fail in my browser, I dunno why, maybe because of "unsupported" attributes? (Extremely frustrating, by the way. Why eliminate these much simpler attributes that worked fine for decades? I don't give a frickin' rip what anyone thinks of my coding style, as long as it WORKS.)

In particular, I use  and the valign doesn't work.
So I tried the following, with never a success:

```
<td align=center vertical-align:top>
<td text-align:center; vertical-align:top>
<td text-align:center; vertical-align:text-top>
<td vertical-align:text-top>
```

Now I'm only more frustrated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't the `vertical-align:top` or `vertical-align:text-top` supposed to be in a `style=""`?

Comment: i think some of them are depreciated a long time ago.

Comment: The title does not correspond to the question at all. The attribute `valign="top"` works, but the attempt at using its CSS counterpart does not work (because of trying to use CSS syntax directly inside HTML).

Comment: If the problem is what the title says, then you need to rewrite the question text and provide code sample that uses the HTML `valign` attribute and explain how it fails to work (expected rendering, actual rendering, browser[s] tested).

Answer (score 15):

The `vertical-align:top` is not supposed to occur in the `td` tag itself. You have to put it in a `style=""` line or in the CSS rules for `td`.

Using `style=""`:

```
<td align="center" style="vertical-align:top">
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:top">
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:text-top">
<td style="vertical-align:text-top">
```

For the CSS method, you will have to give a seperate class or id to each `td` in order for their styles to be different.

Comment: Pitfall to avoid: To "center" vertical-align, its value must be "middle", not "center."

Answer (score 1):

You can use `valign= top` not `valign: top or vertical-align: top` in your html markup and use `vertical-align: top;` in css

In your html you could do this

```
<td align=center valign=top>
```

In your css stylesheet

```
td{vertical-align: top;}
```

And in your inline-style

```
<td align=center style="vertical-align: top;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted `vertical-align:top` use `valign="top"`.

Here is your the code:

```
<td align="center" valign="top">
```

**Note:** Never use `:` in the HTML attributes so instead of using `valign:top` you should use `valign="top"`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp says quite opposite. valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.