# The 'xxxxx' displays at the bottom of the <td> while I want it to appear at the top of the td . How can I achieve it

Tags: html

My code is like,

```
      <div class="content_bottom">
        <div class="wrap">

            <div class="content-bottom-right">
            <div class="product-articles">
              <h3>Our Quality</h3>-->
             <!-- <div class="article" style="clear:both; color:#333;">
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>-->
            <td width="35%"><img src="images/sq1.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/sq2.jpg" alt="" />

  <!--          </td> 

            </tr>
            <tr> -->

            <td valign="top" style="text-align:justify;">xxxxx</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

The 'xxxxx' displays at the bottom of the  while I want it to appear at the top of the td . How can I achieve it.
[image]

** Even adding this > , doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Its slightly hard to understand your problem. Can you reproduce it in a fiddle or provide a link which can make it a bit clearer?

Comment: You see 'We are having ' text. I want it to appear at the top of the <td>, I mean without any empty space left on top of the text.

Comment: I don't know why your code isn't working. I made a fiddle similar to your condition https://fiddle.jshell.net/djaxsxur/ and it seems to work. You must be having some other styling that is causing the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [valign=“top” not working in td](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050098/valign-top-not-working-in-td)

Answer (score 0):

Vertical Align top is not supposed to occur in the td tag itself however you can use it inside css.

```
<td style="vertical-align:text-top">
```

Comment: <td  style="text-align:justify;valign:top;"> this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If that's your complete code then you have not kept that `sq2.jpg` on a `<td>`

Change this code

```
<td width="35%"><img src="images/sq1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/sq2.jpg" alt="" />
```

to

```
<td width="35%"><img src="images/sq1.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="images/sq2.jpg" alt="" /></td>
```

also do `vertical-align:text-top` for the `td` that holds text

Comment: Can anyone pls help

Comment: I am posting the header code of the html page       <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: did it fixed that?